# Building Maven sub-modules in a Gradle project

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a Gradle build working for a bunch of Java and C sub-modules. I would like to add several sub-modules which are incoming from existing code base and are already setup as Maven builds. Is there a way for Gradle to pickup the Maven sub-modules as part of the parent build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, there is no native way to run some maven goal within gradle build script. By the way, it is possible to run a maven goal, just providig a custom task of `Exec` type, which will run a maven build as a command line process. You can read more about this task type [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html).

Furthermore, it is even possible to provide the maven goal artifacts as dependencies for the gradle project, after you build them from custom gradle task and specify the file-dependency with `builtBy` property. You can read about it [in the official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies).

Comment: @NitsanWakart I don't have any at the moment, but you may tako a look at one here https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-exec-mvn-dependency-copy-dependencies/6522